# Display Pop-up message

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have managed to extract out the wanted info from other sheets. It looks something like this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2ujc.png) 
 but now I have no idea on how to display those info. I would like to display only A and J column. something like this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z2aI.png)

And another problem I face is that the number documents will change. For example, in this case there are three documents to display but there could be in stance, where only one or three or even no document to display. I have came out with a code to tackle this problem and display "No document is due" if no document is on the list.

Could someone please help me with this. I am not asking for the full answer, I need some guidance on how to save the wanted info (A and J column) (for various number of documents). Thank youu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through each row containing data, and append the relevant values to an output message. The when the loop is complete, display that message.

Something like this:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lRowMax As Long
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim strPlural As String

    With Sheet1
        lRowMax = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If lRowMax = 1 Then
            strMsg = "No document is due"
        Else
            If lRowMax = 2 Then
                strMsg = "This document requires a revision"
            Else
                strMsg = "These documents require a revision"
            End If
            strMsg = strMsg & vbCr
            For lRow = 2 To lRowMax
                strMsg = strMsg & vbCr & .Cells(lRow, 1).Value & vbTab & .Cells(lRow, 10).Value
            Next lRow
        End If
    End With
    MsgBox strMsg, vbOKOnly, "Reminder"
End Sub
```